# Zoom in and zoom out doesn't work for real time D3 line chart

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, angular2-forms

I created a real time d3 line chart. You can see it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peDzT/1403/).

There are two issues :

1 - While zooming and zooming out both work fine, it doesn't last because the realTime updating of the chart sets the chat back to a non-zoomed state.

How can I make it so the chart maintains it's zoomed-in or zoomed-out state after it's been updated?

Following is the zooming and zoom out code which is not working on refresh. For entire sample code, you can go to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peDzT/1403/).

What I expect in this code is, I should be able to save viewport position so that on refresh I can just use that position and move navigation bar to old position.

```
this.zoom = d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
.translateExtent([[0, 0], [this.width, this.height]])
.extent([[0, 0], [this.width, this.height]])
.on("zoom", ()=> {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") {
    return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  }
  let t = d3.event.transform;;
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "wheel") {
   thisObj.zoomTransform = d3.event.transform;
   }

 if(thisObj.isToUpdateChart && (typeof thisObj.zoomTransform != 'undefined'))
 {
   //t = this.zoomTransform;
   thisObj.isToUpdateChart = false;
   //this.zoomTransform = undefined;
 }
 else
    thisObj.isToUpdateChart = false;
  thisObj.mainXScale.domain(t .rescaleX(thisObj.navXScale).domain());
  let count = 0;
  thisObj.mainLinePath.forEach(linePath => {
    linePath
    // .attr('transform', null)
    // .transition()
    // .duration(this.duration)
    // .ease(this.transition)
    .attr("d", thisObj.mainChartLine[count]);
    count++;
  });
  thisObj.mainXAxisGroup
  // .transition()
  // .duration(this.duration)
  // .ease(this.transition)
  .call( thisObj.mainXAxis);
  thisObj.navGroup.select(".x.brush")
  .call(thisObj.navXBrush.move, thisObj.mainXScale.range().map(t.invertX, t));
});
```

2 - I want to be able to navigate through the main chart by using navigation chart below it. I made it work by maintaining `navViewportLeft` and `isToUpdateChart` positions of `view-port` (of selected area from navigation bar). But I'm not pleased with this solution. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think this question represents a problem, so this is a valid question.